# Why it is so ? And It is without you explicitly do casting

Tags: c++, casting

```
float a = 4.2 ;
double b = 4.2 ;

if(a==b)
  cout<<"True";
else
  cout<<"False";
```

It will give result as "False" .
But when I declare a and b as ,

```
float a = 4.5;
double b =4.5 ;
```

It gives the result "True"

What is happening here ? Can anybody explain it please and its not duplicate as values when given "4.5" or "4.0" it results in "True"

Comment: Needs a better title. :P

Comment: focus on question Sir

Comment: Picard made it so...

Comment: http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf

Comment: No , because then why it gives true when the values fed as "4.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comparison between `double` and `float` gets `float` implicitly converted to `double`. Which means that your `a==b` is interpreted as `(double) a == b`.

The fractional part of `4.5` is an exact power of `2`: 0.5 == 2<sup>-2</sup>. This value is represented in binary floating-point format *precisely*

```
4.5 dec = 100.1 bin
```

And it is represented precisely in both `double` and `float`. So, the comparison compares `4.5` to `4.5` and the result is `true`.

`4.2` is requires an *infinite* periodic sum of powers of `2` to represent.

```
4.2 dec = 100.0011001100110011... bin = 100.(0011) bin
```

For this reason it is represented in `double` and `float` only approximately - the infinite sequence gets trimmed in one way or another. Since `float` has less precision than `double`, the value stored in `float` ends up being different than the value stored in `double`. In `double` you get something like `4.1999998092651367`, while in `float` you get something like `4.2000000000000002`. The conversion to `double` in `(double) a == b` cannot make the values to "match" and the result is `false`.

Comment: what u mean by exact sum of powers of 2 ?   what in the case of values to be "4.0" ?

Comment: @Bhavesh Kumar: I'm talking about the fractional part specifically in this case. `0.5` is a power of `2` by itself. `0.2` is not. The whole part does not matter in this case (as long as it is small). You can repeat your experiments with `0.5` and `0.2` respectively and observe the same results.

Comment: why we check this with power of "2" , I mean it can be any else number though ?

Comment: @Bhavesh Kumar: Floating-point numbers on most platforms are stored in IEEE754 formats, which are **binary** floating-point formats. All values are represents through sums of powers of `2`. If a value is representable as a *finite* sum of powers of `2`, then it is possible to represent it precisely (depends on the actual powers not being to spread to far apart). If a value requires an *infinitely long* sum of powers of `2`, then it cannot be represented precisely. That is exactly the difference between `4.5` and `4.2`.

Comment: `4.5` in binary is just `100.1`. `4.2` in binary is `100.0011001100110011...` and so on ad infinitum. See the difference?

Comment: thank you Sir , you cleared my doubt very well

Answer (score 0):

Floating point variables cannot accurately represent all values.   In particular, the values `0.1` and `0.2` (in decimal) cannot be exactly represented, and only an approximation is stored in the variable.

A variable of type `double` will store such values to greater precision than will a `float` (i.e. it will give a better approximation).   So the two values will not be equal.

To understand, understand that floating point variables typically work with base 2 (binary fractions).   Then try to represent 1/10 (decimal) in base 2.   The result is an infinite series.   It is the same phenomenon that results in 1/3 being represented in decimal as 0.33333.... (an infinite number of  digits).      The only differences is that, in binary, a different set of values have an infinite number of digits.   One of the affected values is 1/10.